# Entity list doesn't reload after remove

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading

Problem with lazy loading after remove child entity. I've got 2 entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Projects")
public class Project implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private User author;

    @NotNull
    private boolean active;

    @NotNull
    private boolean privacy;

    private String logoPath;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "author", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Project> createdProjects;
```

And a test:

```
@Test
    public void should_delete_created_project()
    {
        // given
        User user = givenUser();
        Project project = givenCreatedProject(user);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, user.getCreatedProjects().size());

        // when
        List<Project> projects = projectService.findByUserId(user.getId());
        System.out.println("User's projects before remove: " + projects);
        deleteProject(project);

        // then
        user = userService.findById(user.getId());
        System.out.println("User's projects after remove (from findByUserId): " + projectService.findByUserId(user.getId()));
        System.out.println("User's projects after remove: " + user.getCreatedProjects());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, user.getCreatedProjects().size());
    }
```

Test doesn't pass - method projectService.findByUserId(user.getId()) returns updated list of projects (size = 0), but when I check it by user.getCreatedProjects() method - it returns list before a transaction.

Delete method is marked as @Transactional. Problem disappeares when I add fetch = FetchType.EAGER in User entity, but I don't want to go this way. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: you could try a em.flush() in the deleteProject() method (I guess this is where you call your entityManager?). JPA will only make a transaction in the Database when the buffer is full, unless you explicitly tell it to with the flush() method. Be aware this can also lead to DB transaction overhead when you apply this to large projects.

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert didn't help. I still get "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.createdProjects" message.

Comment: you can try to force the new list/Set of projects to be loaded using a little work around in your tests. new HashSet<Project>(user.getCreatedProjects()) can force all the projects to be loaded.
Although i think you're code is working fine when the test passes on fetch type Eager, but it fails because of JPA transactional buffer with lazy loading.